# How to point to a table and download csv files from a website using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Posted 11 days ago
I am automating a process wherein I have to login to website and download only the CSV files from the different types of files available on that website.

I am trying to do the below steps :

1. Launch the url - "https://www.shipper-ml.com"
2. Login. username - zzzzzzzzzzz Password- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
3. Navigate to "https://www.shipper-ml.com/viewReports.do/" page.

I am trying to download the csv files from the above website

Is it possible to achieve this using selenium. If yes, can somebody help me on how to go ahead ?

```
package package1;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Tutorials1 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
String exepath="C:\\Users\\sh370472\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32 (2)\\chromedriver.exe";
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exepath);
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.shipper-ml.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("inpUserId")).sendKeys("zzzzzzzzzzz");
driver.findElement(By.id("inpPassword")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogonLabel")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.get("https://www.shipper-ml.com/viewReports.do");
}
```

}

Comment: Clicking on the link when you are logged in doesn't help? Will be better, if you show, what you already have (code) and if you have any mistake.

Comment: Can you please, post the code, it will be helpful for us to help you!

Comment: I have posted the code. I am not sure how to go ahead after that.

Comment: @Shivangi The post seems to contain your username and password to the site. You should change them immediately!

Comment: Can you help me with question

Comment: Anybody here who can help ?

Comment: Please describe desired and current behavior. If you run your code, do you get eny exception? If yes, what exception? HTML source code would be helpful as well.

Comment: It should download files from the table that is there in the website but I am not sure how to proceed. I don't know how to point to that table. Can you help me ? @pburgr

Comment: Please add html source code (or dummy credentials to be able to login). If it is possible to download files menualy by clicking some links (no matter if they are in some table) it is always possible to make it via selenium.